# Get len of the ArrayField Postgres Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I've a model:-

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    field1 = ArrayField(models.IntegerField())
```

I want to get the top10 objects of ModelA having maximum length of field1. I see that a `len` filter is available in [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#len), but that just does not serves my purpose.

How can I get top10 objects having maximum length of field1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to get the frequency of the elements in the array as well:-

```
q = """
with norm (id, element) as (
    select id, unnest(field1) from model;
)
select id, sum(case when element = 2 then 1 else 0 end)  as count
from norm
group by id
order by count
limit 10;
"""


a = Model.objects.raw(q)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are sure your array is 1-dimensional, you can use PostgreSQL function `cardinality`

```
ModelA.objects.extra(select={'length':'cardinality(field1)'}).order_by('length')
```

Or, using `array_length` function (with second argument being the number of dimensions sought)

```
ModelA.objects.extra(select={'length':'array_length(field1,1)'}).order_by('length')
```

Comment: Thanks @Ian. Thanks a lot. I'm having 1-D array for sure. Can I also find the total frequencies of an element in an ArrayField?

Comment: Also, while running the first command, I get the following error:- `LINE 1: SELECT (cardinality(field1)) AS "length", "module_modela...
                ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: Still the same error. I tried this command of yours.`ModelA.objects.extra(select={'length': 'cardinality(field1)'}).order_by('length')`

Comment: upon printing the query, I get the following:-`SELECT (cardinality(field1)) AS "length", "moduleName"."id", "moduleName"."field1" FROM "moduleName_modela" ORDER BY "length" ASC`

Comment: Seems like I'd a problem with postgres. Reinstalled it and it was working. Thanks :)

Comment: Can I also find the total frequencies of an element in an ArrayField?

Comment: Wish I had a solution for frequencies but I don't! If you find something please post it, would be interested in seeing it.